# “Master's” vs. “master”

Tags: terminology, grammar

I have to write a letter about a graduate course abroad. I began it like this:

> I am writing this letter to apply for XXX Master in XXXX.

and ended with:

> I am absolutely sure that I will complete Master's program in XXX.

So here is my question: Is it okay to use both “Master in” and “Master’s in” in one letter? What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Master's* is an abbreviated form of *master's degree*, and it is considered an informal term by several dictionaries (e.g., [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/master's), [MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/master-s)).

*Master* is just an even more abbreviated form, which is usually not reported in the dictionaries with that meaning (but see note below).

In a formal letter I would use the full form *master's degree*, but should you choose to use one of the two abbreviated forms, try to be consistent and don't use both forms in the same text. Inconsistencies can be interpreted as a sign of sloppiness, and you don't want to give this impression while applying for a degree or a position.

Thus, I would write:

> I am writing this letter to apply for XXX Master's degree in XXXX.

and

> I am absolutely sure that I will complete *the* Master's degree program in XXX.

Check also what is the denomination used in the university documentation: how do they refer to their own programs?

*Note:* The [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/master) reports for *master* also the following meaning (meaning n. 5 in the linked definition):

> **5** [count] : a person who has received a master's degree

Comment: So in my case I changed sentences to:
"I am writing this letter to apply for XXX Master in XXXX." or Master's degree?
and
"I am absolutely sure that I will complete Master's degree in XXX".

Comment: @Jacob See the edit.